# JSON.parse syntax error while JSONLint tell me that json string is valid

Tags: php, json, validation, parsing, jsonlint

I used the PHP built-in function `json_encode()` to covert an object array to `json string`. Then I use AJAX method to get the `xmlhttp.responseText`. I use `document.write(xmlhttp.responseText)` to check the response string. For example, the string is as follow:

```
{"index":0,"marks":2}
```

But, when I use `JSON.parse()` to parse the JSON string, I get a syntax error. So, I copy this string to `JSONLint` to check whether it's valid, the result is no.

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    "index": 0
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

But when I input it by hand, it's valid. Why?

Comment: which is it? `"index":0` or `"index":"0"`?

Answer (score 1):

You may have some [zero-width whitespace character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) or similar in your responseText.

As a note, I highly recommend using `console.log` instead of `document.write` for debugging.